# Why do you need an browser extension like MetaMask to make transactions on Ethereum?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, metamask

What is stopping web apps from accessing and making transactions directly on the blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you don’t need MetaMask. You do need access to a node on the blockchain. That can be achieved by running a fully synced or light node on a client, or by having your web app talk to a server connected to a node. MetaMask is one of many ways. It just happens to be the most popular (right now).

Comment: I would add that MetaMask serves an important security role: it holds the user's private key so they don't have to share it with the web app. Without MetaMask (or Mist or a similar solution), the user has to trust each web app they use to an extreme extent. If using MetaMask, the user only needs to trust MetaMask.